# Webform is currently not enabled on any content types

Tags: webforms

I have installed the "Webform" module with no problem, but when I create a new webform, I don't have the possibility to add a new field. I have checked the section `config/content/webform`. I get this message "**Webform is currently not enabled on any content types**". Since I am new to Drupal, I don't know what to do,can somebody help me please?

Comment: please make sure to mention Drupal version in your posts. Tagging is better eg. 8 for Drupal 8

Comment: I did this actually.

Comment: Can't see the tag though.

Comment: Sorry wrong comment ... I will do it in the futur, Sir Yes Sir ! :D

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have enabled WEBFORM in the Drupal menu modules

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/75049)

Comment: "Drupal Menu Modules" is the Answer - and I do except the user to know at least Drupal Menu - Thanks for the Review @Adrian Cid Almaguer next time will try to fill the page

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer lies in the question.

"Do you have Webform enabled for any 'content types'?"

You can check this by navigating to the 'content type' overview page: `admin/structure/types`

Then click any of the available 'content types' and check if Webfrom is enabled.

This functionality is located under the Webform Tab, i.e. Enable webform functionality.

Comment: I proceeded the same way and the problem is solved indeed... Thank you so much for your help !